# Как получить name and value of all context-parameters в jsp с помощью JSTL и EL(НЕ ДУБЛИКАТ!)

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet, jstl

Вот,вроде-бы,EL хорошая штука.Тебе не нужно делать вставки,которые очень громоздкие.

```
<% String name = (String) request.getAttribute("name"); %>
```

Можно заменить на красивое EL :

```
${name} , ${requestScope.name}
```

Но,как мне получить,допустим, context-param с помощью EL?

Я знаю про существование EL Implicit Objects.Большинство из них предоставляет из себя Map,меньше - массив типа String

Пытаюсь вот так :

```
${pageContext.servletContext.?}
```

Кажется,что servletContext по-типу javaBean и нам нужно указать какое-то property.
А property Только одно доступное связанное с init-parameters:

```
${pageContext.servletContext.initParameterNames}
```

Толку от него я не нашел.Можно конечно через c:forEach прогнать :

```
<c:forEach var = "param" items = "pageContext.servletContext.initParameterNames">
 <c:out value = "${param}">
</forEach>
```

По идее должен получить хотя-бы имена.
В итоге - не выводит даже имен.
Вот сами context-param :

```
<context-param>
<param-name>name</param-name>
<param-value>Sckoriy</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>surname</param-name>
<param-value>Sckoriy</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Нашел интересную вещь ,которую предлагают для решению моего вопроса :

```
${initParam.parameterName}
```

Но это же не правильно!

> InitParam - Конфигурационные параметры, указанные для страницы или сервлета в дескрипторе приложений web.xml.НЕ ДЛЯ параметров контекста!

Но,если попытаться получить параметр-контекста таким образом :

```
${initParam["name"]}
${initParam["surname"]}
```

То все работает,что не есть логичным.Ибо это initParam jsp.А если у нас два параметра разной области будут иметь одинаковые ключи :

```
<context-param>
<param-name>name</param-name>
<param-value>Sckoriy</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>InitParameters</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/JB.jsp</jsp-file>
<init-param>
    <param-name>name</param-name>  
    <param-value>Sckorik_Sergest@ukr.net</param-value>  
</init-param>
</servlet>


<c:out value = "${initParam["name"]}"
```

> Ответ будет - Sckoriy.Параметр из контекста приложения ,а не контекста jsp.

Comment: А что так нельзя `#{pageContext.servletContext.getInitParameter('paramName')}`? EL же умеет вызывать функции, а в servletContext есть функция getInitParameter

Comment: Я не уверен,что именно так можно вызывать функции в EL.Точней,так нельзя.Чтобы вызвать функцию в EL нужно делать Tag Lib Descriptor.И делать вызов по типу такого : ${mine:getInitParameter} , но это совсем не-то.У нас уже есть map<String , String> для initParameter.Ладно,буду рыть дальше.Может я вообще не понимаю как forEach транслируется...

Comment: Погуглите EL Method Expressions.Почитайте документацию по EL Вот такое можн найти `#{ELBean.saveFirstName(firstName.value.toString().concat('(passed)'))}` Вон сколько вызовов функций в одном выражении. 1, 2, 3